# Highlight next menu item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi I am trying to implement a feature in my website where when i click on a menu item the highlight should be able to flow to the next menu item.From the below example if I click on `people` the menu should highlight `people` and then also highlight the next case in the menu which is `tourist`.. I am using CSS for hover but what I understand from other posts is that a:active doesn't work with CSS?

This is what I have so done so far:

**HTML**

```
<section id="nav">    
    <li><a class="nav" href="People.html">People</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Tourist.html">Tourist</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Joints.html">Joints</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Project.html">Project</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="cafes.html">cafes</a></li>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $('#nav').on('click','.nav', function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('#nav').find('.active').removeClass('active').end().end().addClass('active');
            $(activeTab).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    min-width:1300px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#nav li{
    display:inline;
}

#nav .nav{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:16pt;
    line-height:18pt;
    font-weight:400;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top:35px;
    padding:0px 3px 2px 3px;
}

#nav .nav:hover{
    background:#FFFF00;
    color:#000;
}

.active{
    background:#FFFF00;
    color:#000;
}
```

Please help me with this.I am stuck up on this

Comment: `:active` works, but not the way you think. an element is `active` when you hold the mouse pressed on it, or hold the finger on the element. once you stop, its not active anymore.

Comment: @Banana ..is the above scenario possible..am confused a bit

Comment: everything is possible if you use javascript. i just cant understand how your code is related to what you are trying to achieve... just to make it clear, you simply want to highlight 2 menu items (clicked one + next one) right?

Comment: @Banana  No want to highlight the next menu

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you (if I understand the question correctly):

```
$('#nav').on('click','.nav', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // remove all "active" classes:
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    // find the next menu item and append "active" class:
    $(this).parent().next('li').find('.nav').addClass('active');
    $(activeTab).show();
});
```

Add `!important` to `.active` styles (you need to override parent dependent styles, as you set them like: `#nav .nav`):

```
.active{
    background:#FFFF00 !important;
    color:#000 !important;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/34qof51z/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to highlight the next item in the menu, you simply need to retrieve the index of the menu item (index of the `<li>` in your case), and calculate the next one:

**UPDATE:**

added animation to snippet

```js
$(function () {
    $('#nav').on('click', '.nav', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       var NextMenuID = ($(this).parent().index()+1)%$(this).parent().parent().children().length;
        var NextItem =$('#nav .nav').eq(NextMenuID);
        $('#nav .nav').removeClass("active");
        var x1=$(this).offset().left;
        var y1=$(this).offset().top;
        var width1=$(this).width();
        var height1=$(this).height();
        
        var x2=NextItem.offset().left;
        var y2=NextItem.offset().top;
        var width2=NextItem.width();
        var height2=NextItem.height();
        var slidingDiv=$("<div/>");
        slidingDiv.css({
            "width":width1,
            "height":height1,
            "left":x1,
            "top":y1,
            "display":"block",
            "position":"absolute",
            "background":"#FFFF00",
            "padding":"0px 3px 2px 3px"
        }).appendTo($("body")).animate({
            "width":width2,
            "height":height2,
            "left":x2,
            "top":y2,
        },function(){ 
            NextItem.addClass("active");
            slidingDiv.remove();
        });
        
      
        //$(activeTab).show();
    });
});
```

```css
#nav {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
#nav .nav {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:16pt;
    line-height:18pt;
    font-weight:400;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top:35px;
    padding:0px 3px 2px 3px;
}
#nav .nav:hover {
    background:#FFFF00;
    color:#000;
}
.active {
    background:#FFFF00 !important;
    color:#000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="nav">
    <li><a class="nav" href="People.html">People</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="nav active" href="Tourist.html">Tourist</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Joints.html">Joints</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Project.html">Project</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="Products.html">Products</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="cafes.html">cafes</a>

    </li>
</section>
```

If you have any questions about the example, feel free to ask.